# android : error in email sending

Tags: android

my requirement is to send email from smtp server.

for that i am using following code:

```
package com.ixpenseit.email;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
     
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;
private String[] _to;
private String _from;
private String _port;    
private String _sport;
private String _host;
private String _subject;
private String _body;
private boolean _auth;
private Multipart _multipart;
     
private Mail() {
_auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on
_multipart = new MimeMultipart();
}
     
public Mail(String smtpserver, String smtpport, String smtpsocketfactoryport) {
_host = smtpserver; // default smtp server
_port = smtpport; // default smtp port
_sport = smtpsocketfactoryport; // default socketfactory port
_auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on
_multipart = new MimeMultipart();
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}
     
public void setCredential(String username, String password) {
_user = username;
pass = password;
}
     
public boolean send() throws AddressException, MessagingException{
Properties props = _setProperties();
if (Utility.isValidString(_user) && Utility.isValidString(_pass) && _to != null && Utility.isValidString(_from)&& Utility.isValidString(_body)&& Utility.isValidString(_subject) &&_to.length  0) {
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));
     
InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
}
msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO,addressTo);
     
msg.setSubject(_subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
     
// setup message body
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
     
// Put parts in message
 msg.setContent(_multipart);
// send email
Transport.send(msg);
return true;
} else {return false;}
}
     
public void setEmail(String[] to, String from, String subject, String body) {
_to = to;
_body = body;
_subject = subject;
_from = from;
}
     
public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
     
public void addAttachment(String folder, String filename) throws Exception {
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(folder + "" + filename);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
     
@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}
     
private Properties _setProperties() {
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
if (_auth) {props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");}
props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",_sport);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
return props;
}
}
```

main activity code is :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            sendEmail();
        }
private void sendEmail()  {
        //Mail m = new Mail("smtp.gmail.com", "465", "465");
        
        Mail m = new Mail("smtp.dummy.com", "27", "27");
        m.setCredential("abc@dummy", "dummy");
        
        String[] toArr = { "to@gmail.com" };
        m.setEmail(toArr, "from@no-spam.com", "Auto Generated Expense Report",
                "Auto Generated Body.");
        
            try {
                if (m.send()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Email.this, "Email was sent successfully.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Email.this, "Email was not sent.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
            }
```

download jars from the following link:

> [mail.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar)
>
> [activation.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar)
>
> [additionnal.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar)

the above code working good for gmail.
But when i tried it with hotmail, yahoo and my own smtp server then is show the following exception

> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):   nested
> exception is: 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):
> java.io.IOException: SSL handshake
> failure: Failure in SSL library,
> usually a protocol error 02-24
> 12:34:31.347: ERROR/MailApp(3668):
> error:140770FC:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
> protocol
> (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:585
> 0xaf589bac:0x00000000) 02-24
> 12:34:31.347: ERROR/MailApp(3668):
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> com.ixpenseit.email.Mail.send(Mail.java:106)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> com.email.Email.sendEmail(Email.java:48)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> com.email.Email.onCreate(Email.java:22)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method) 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668): Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: SSL handshake
> failure: Failure in SSL library,
> usually a protocol error 02-24
> 12:34:31.347: ERROR/MailApp(3668):
> error:140770FC:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
> protocol
> (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:585
> 0xaf589bac:0x00000000) 02-24
> 12:34:31.347: ERROR/MailApp(3668):
> at
> org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativeconnect(Native
> Method) 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:305)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:502)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:443)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:1449)
> 02-24 12:34:31.347:
> ERROR/MailApp(3668):     at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1366)

how can i try it with other smtp server?

help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the similar exception. I added the internet permission in the manifest and it started working.
Try the same.