# Send email from app - 'MailApp' Error

Tags: android, eclipse, email

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101976/android-error-in-email-sending) while trying to find an answer to and error I get by implementing [the last part of this tutorial.](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) However, it seemed that the question was rather aimed at applying the mentioned tutorial to mail servers other than gmail. In my case, I really just want this to work - I'm developing something for an Honours project at the University of Pretoria in South Africa, and I don't really mind if it does not work for all email addresses - at the moment I just want it to work for mine.

This section cannot be resolved in Eclipse (for interest sake - I'm developing for Android 2.2 - I always wonder when reading questions and answers, so I thought to tell you):

```
if(m.send()) { 
              Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else { 
              Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
```

Eclipse gives me the following: MailApp cannot be resolved to a type

And then the following options:

```
 9 quick fixes available:

   Change to 'Mail' (mypackage)
   Change to 'MailTo' (android.net)
   Create class 'MailApp'
   Crate interface 'MailApp'
   Add type parameter 'MailApp' to 'MyActivity'
   Add type parameter 'MailApp' to 'onClick(View)'
   Add type parameter 'MailApp' to 'onCreate(Bundle)'
   Create enum 'MailApp
   Fix project setup...
```

When choosing option 1 and 2, this part becomes the error: ...makeText(Mail.this, "...); "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Mail, String, int)"

That said, in many other examples of sending mails from applications - as the mentioned tutorial suggests - MailApp is used everywhere, so I don't know how to exclude it, change it or what to change if not 'MailApp'.

I would appreciate any feedback or suggested links.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
MailApp.this
```

to just

```
this
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in the example the name of the activity class is `MailApp`.

But in your case you only need `Context`, so you can use reference to your activity.