# Sending Emails without User Intervention (no Intents) in Android via JavaMail API

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

for this i used the following code:

```
package moin.sms;

import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  public String _user; 
  public String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public void Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 



  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 
  public String[] getTo(){
      return _to;
  }

  public void setTo(String[] _to){
      this._to = _to;
  }

  public String getFrom(){
      return _from;
  }

  public void setFrom(String _from){
      this._from=_from;
  }

  public String getSubject(){
      return _subject;
  }

  public void setSubject(String _subject){
      this._subject=_subject;
  }



}
```

The activity calling this is as:

```
package moin.sms;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GmailSendActivity extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
          public void onClick(View view) { 
            Mail m = new Mail();
            m._user = "**My Gmail ID**"; // username 
            m._pass = "**PASSWORD**"; // password

            String[] toArr = {"cistoran@live.com", "ivan017@gmail.com"}; 
            m.setTo(toArr); 
            m.setFrom("moin18@gmail.com"); 
            m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
            m.setBody("Email body."); 

            try { 
              m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

              if(m.send()) { 
                Toast.makeText(GmailSendActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              } else { 
                Toast.makeText(GmailSendActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              } 
            } catch(Exception e) { 
              //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
            } 
          t1.setText("to :"+m.getTo().toString()+"* from: "+m.getFrom()+"* Sub: "+m.getSubject()+"* Messg: "+m.getBody());  
          } 

        }); 
      } 

}
```

I have already added the necessary jars. i.e

**(1) mail.jar**

**(2) activation.jar**

**(3) additional.jar**

But when i run it in Eclipse IDE, following error message is displayed on The LogCat:

```
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): Could not send email
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at moin.sms.Mail.addAttachment(Mail.java:117)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at moin.sms.GmailSendActivity$1.onClick(GmailSendActivity.java:34)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-10 11:20:06.682: E/MailApp(435): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It isn't even running on the mobile, i have also added the INTERNET permission in manifest file. Could anybody tell whats the problem here?

Comment: have you took necessary permission of `ExternalStorage`?

Comment: like as? sorry i'm new here. please elaborate

Comment: you have to take permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in manifest.

Comment: i now added this permisson. could you please tell me how to put the path for example suppose i need to send image with name "ppp.jpg" how to specify its pathname. Would it be like /sdcard/ppp.jpg or /E:/ppp.jpd or /SD Card/ppp.jpg

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "ppp.jpg";

Comment: what this line does? i mean how it prforms the task? Checks for the file in whole memory?

Comment: this will give you a "String" formatted path of your source file.

Comment: that means the code would be like this: is it? m.addAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "ppp.jpg");

Comment: i tried it.. but still it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `m.addAttachment("/mnt/sdcard/filelocation");`

or even better:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "myaudio.3gpp"
```

Also, check if you have added the following permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i now added this permisson. could you please tell me how to put the path for example suppose i need to send image with name "ppp.jpg" how to specify its pathname. Would it be like

    /sdcard/ppp.jpg
or
    /E:/ppp.jpd
or
    /SD Card/ppp.jpg

Comment: did you tried like this: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "ppp.jpg"`??

Comment: yeah i tried that as well but still its not working.. i also tried removing the addAttachment fuction. thought might be it isn't letting me to do the send mail operation. I think the problem is somehere else

Comment: I used it withing the function this way, 
     m.addAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "ppp.jpg");

not getting where the problem is

Comment: are you able to send without attachment??

Comment: No. without that also it didn't work. Are you sure gmail allows us to send email this way?

Comment: yes, it allows, debug your session to find the problem using session.setDebug(true)

Comment: its my complete code to the application. Do i need to do any another as well? like as asking for any kind of license with gmail or something?

Answer (score 0):

As much I got to know from your `LogCat` Issue is at code snippet:-

```
m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation");
```

What exactly you are trying to attach with the mail?

Comment: it is an audio file. I tried it even to run through mobile but it isn't working

Comment: well i think i didn't specify the exact file location. May i get your gmail id? i need to ask few more things. mine is moin18@gmail.com

Comment: I added you, did u get request, mine is harryb87@gmail.com

Comment: i didn't got the request but i just sent you an email.

Comment: i used this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101976/android-error-in-email-sending?rq=1

it worked but now if i am running it again in app its not performing any action. Does gmail use to block the app? don't know why its not letting to send any email now. Even no error flashes